# Ambiguous Grids

Tags: no-computers, grid-deduction, reverse-puzzling

After six to eight weeks of waiting, your Shmikoli™ Ambiguous Grid Deduction Puzzle Set has finally arrived!

You tear into the box only to discover that the instructions are missing. You shouldn't have ordered from such a questionable vendor. Still, at the price of one upvote, the item was a steal.

From [previous experience](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49892/three-for-the-price-of-one), you know that each grid depicts *two* uniquely solvable grid deduction puzzles. You have no idea which types of puzzles can be solved on which of the three grids, but you resolve to figure it out.

**Grid 1**

[image]

**Grid 2**

[image]

**Grid 3**

[image]

**Hint 1**

> Having exhausted your knowledge of various puzzle types, you consult a helpful [website](http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/index.htm).

**Hint 2**

> In particular, [this page](http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Linienraetsel.htm) and [this page](http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Polyominos.htm) seem promising.

---

**Update**

I have corrected an error in the first grid. The puzzle types for that grid remain the same.

Comment: Shmikoli, schmikoli.

Comment: Gah, grid 1 can *almost* be solved uniquely as a Cave/Corral...

Comment: Why is this not  three separate questions?

Answer (score 5):

## Partial Answer

### Grid 1

> Shikakuro:
>  [image]
>  Kuromasu:
>  [image]

### Grid 2

> Five Cells:
>  [image]

### Grid 3

> Nurikabe:
>  [image]

That's all I've found that's unique, and I've gone through all the Nikoli puzzles on their homepage. The only other options I can think of are

> 1 Kurotto and 1 Sashigane, neither of which seems particularly promising. (Kurodoko leads to a contradiction on 2.)

The other puzzle options from Nikoli (that don't use other elements and have the right amount of clues) are:

> Akari (not possible for 1, leads to contradiction on 2 and 3)
>  Fillomino (too many options for all of them)
>  Hashi (none are aligned right)
>  Kurotto (possible for 1, too many solutions for 2 and 3)
>  Numberlink (no pairs)
>  Nurikabe (used for 3, not workable for 1 or 2)
>  Sashigane (contradiction on 1, too small clues on 2 and 3)
>  Shakashaka (too big clues on 1, contradiction on 2 and 3)
>  Shikaku (used for 1, not possible for 2 and 3)
>  Slitherlink (too big clues on 1 and 3, too many solutions for 2)

Other possible non-Nikoli-homepage puzzles:

> Cave/Corral/BAG, Tapa, Tapa-like loop...

Answer (score 4):

*Partial Answer*

Grid 1:

> [Range](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/range.html)/[Rectangle](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/rect.html)
>  [image: Range/Rectangle]

Grid 2:

> [Palisade](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/palisade.html)/?
>  [image: Palisade/?]

Comment: Well these are neat :) Thanks for the links so I can learn some new puzzles

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice this answer! Sorry if it looks like I was stealing from you - I came up with both of those myself too

Comment: There is a mistake in your Range solution for the first grid. The 9 only has 8 tiles AND the middle square is ambiguous. Even if fixing the mistake, the middle square will still pose a problem which gives us two possibilities and thus no unique solution.

Comment: @wl, grid 1 was indeed supposed to be a Kuromasu (or Range). I overlooked the fact that the middle square could be either white or black. Unfortunately, there's no way for me to fix it without ruining the Shikaku (or Rectangle).

Comment: sorry, fixed Range

Comment: @Silenus - It's also known as a Kurodoko, and that's *exactly* how I tried to solve it before noticing the mistake :/

Comment: @Deusovi and Sconibulus, I have corrected the first grid. The Kuromasu/Range/Kurodoko should be unique now.

Comment: That island solution doesn't seem to work. For instance, the 1 in the bottom left should be a 2, since it can access both white squares above it. It seems like you've solved it as an orthogonal Minesweeper, but in that case it's non-unique.

Comment: Yep I was super wrong, misunderstood how the puzzle works

Answer (score 0):

*partial answer*

Grid 2:

> A slitherlink: [image: slitherlink grid 2]

Comment: That's not unique.